# What to do with a nearly duplicate question from a sister site that wasn't cross-posted?

Tags: discussion

This question was asked recently: [Specificness of Tablespace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177511/specificness-of-tablespace)

There is a nearly identical question that was asked on Stack Overflow 10 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291317/should-an-oracle-database-have-more-than-one-tablespace-for-data-storage).

I don't think that I could provide a better answer than Justin Cave's excellent answer.  The same points that Justin pointed out are still applicable today.  I did, however, add a comment on the recent question linking back to the Stack Overflow answer.

I don't think that the question can/should be closed.  It doesn't appear to be a duplicate on the DBA site (the closest match that I found on the DBA site is [What are the benefits of using a different tablespace for a new user schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-different-tablespace-for-a-new-user-schema?rq=1), but even that question isn't exactly a duplicate).

So, what do we do with the question that was just asked?

The best 2 possibilities I could come up with:

**1)**  Do nothing.  Future visitors still have the link back to Justin's answer.  However, I know that comments can go away...

**2)**  Copy/paste Justin Cave's answer into a Quote block, give him credit, then add the link to the stack overflow question/answer.  However, this almost feels like a simple grab for more points (which, despite my low points, I really don't care about the point system).

Comment: You can do the 2nd. You wait until people vote 2,3, (10) times, then you mark as Community Wiki. You still get rep (little or much, you decide when to mark as CW) and we have the answer here, too. Everyone wins ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thank you for your input... I've answered the question.  I'll leave it like that for now unless people post here with other opinions (or I start amassing down votes).

Comment: I do have a 3rd option, invite [Justin Cave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/555/justin-cave), already a member of this site, to repost, that answer himself.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Good idea.  However, since my answer has already been accepted, deleting my answer, then asking Justin to post an answer would probably be detrimental.  I did however post on his original answer pointing to my answer and asked him to edit my answer (or post one of his own) if he feels it necessary, especially if his opinion on this topic has changed in the past 10 years.

Comment: Just a thought for the future. Especially with an expert who's active elswhere on SE